# assign position to tree nodes in a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

I've been stuck on this for a while: basically I want to assign positions to tree nodes based on their relative position to left most nodes: all nodes on left most are 0, parent node position should be largest child node position of its immediate left sibling node + 1.

An example shown below: (number is the position of that node; can be any tree, not necessarily binary)

```
root
 0--
 |  \
 0   2----
 |\  |    \
 0 1 2--   5
     |\ \  |\
     2 3 4 5 6
             |\
             6 7
```

I think I should use recursion but I'm kinda stuck on how to proceed. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Question is not clear....can you elaborate a bit...Is it a binary tree? in your diagram, which are nodes and which are positions?

Comment: Your example seems clear, but just for clarification: "largest child node position of its immediate left sibling node + 1" doesn't specify the position of a node with no immediate left sibling (such as the bottommost 2 in your example). This is related to an ambiguity in the definition of "leftmost", which could also mean the leftmost node at a particular level.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write recursive code which assigns the leftmost position. and returns the righmost position of a subtree. The return value is used to process the subtree of the next child.

For example, in C++:

```c
    int Assign(int pos, node *p) {
       p->pos = pos;
       for(node *child : p->children)
         pos = Assign(pos, child);
       return pos + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your example, the *leaves* of the tree have a sequential numbering. Parents get the same value as their left most child.

So the idea is to use a depth-first traversal (recursion). Here is one way you could assign the positions during such a traversal:

- when you arrive at a leaf: assign it the next available position number;
- otherwise, first assign positions to the node's children recursively, and then copy the number of the left-most child and assign it to the current node

Here is an implementation in JavaScript where the graph is encoded using an adjacency list. The example tree is taken as input, and the positions are output in BFS order (level by level, from left to right):

```js
function getPositions(adj) {
    // One entry per node:
    let positions = Array(adj.length);
    let nextPos = 0;
    
    function dfs(nodeId) {
        if (adj[nodeId].length === 0) { // a leaf
            positions[nodeId] = nextPos++;
            return;
        }
        for (let neighborId of adj[nodeId]) {
            dfs(neighborId);
        }
        // Copy position from left-most child
        positions[nodeId] = positions[adj[nodeId][0]];
    }
    
    dfs(0);
    
    return positions;
}

// Example tree defined with an adjacency list
let adj = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
    [],
    [],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [10, 11],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [12, 13],
    [],
    []
];
/* Nodes identified by their index:
 0--
 |  \
 1   2----
 |\  |    \
 3 4 5--   6
     |\ \  | \
     7 8 9 10 11
              |\
             12 13
*/
let positions = getPositions(adj);

console.log("Positions listed in BFS order:")
console.log(...positions);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to align with the example provided in the question.

Comment: @rici, what particular difference you see? I think it is fine. Just realise that I numbered the nodes by their BFS order, just to give them an ID for the use of the adjacency list.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your diagram.

Comment: Ok, i definitely misunderstood the diagram. Sorry.